# What will happen if the receiver lost the IV in CBC (cipher block chaining) or didn't receive at all?

Tags: c#

In Cipher Block Chaining cryptography system
If I encrypted a message in Cipher Block Chaining!
The receiver in any way lost the IV or didn't receive the IV at all? 
What will happen?

Comment: Obviously the first block can't be decrypted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a generic question about cryptography, not a specific programming problem. We do have a crypto stack exchange site where it may be more on-topic.